Incluir paquete propio en dependencies flutter
Buenas tengo un paquete propio creado con Widgets en Flutter, el cual tengo en un servidor. El caso esque tengo el siguiente codigo en el archivo 'pubspec.yaml' en dependencies:
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_base:
    path: "//ipServidor/Home/FranCarrascosa/flutter_base"
  go_router:
  http:
  intl:
  shared_preferences: 

El caso es que no me coje esta ruta, alguien podria decirme el error o como hacerlo ?¿

Solucionado, la ruta a poner es la siguiente:
flutter_base:
path: "\\ip\Home\FranCarrascosa\flutter_base"
